# Unable to Inflate OptionsMenu in Android

Tags: java, android-menu

When I run my autogenerated `HelloWorldActivity.java`, everything is fine. But as soon as I inflate an `OptionsMenu`, the app blinks for once in my phone and then it gets closed and nothing happens then. Previously I could do this but now its not just happening. Don't know why. There are no errors and exceptions as well. Following is the code in Java.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println("Inside onCreateOptionsMenu");
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        System.out.println("Inside MenuInflater");
        mi.inflate(R.menu.menu_helloworld_to_registration, menu);//this line has some bug
        System.out.println("Inside menu.xml file");//Because I cannot see this in my Logcat
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Menu XML file inside MenuFolder(res/menu).**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mi_registration"
    android:title="Registration"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="onRegistration"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"></item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`. You need `Toolbar` for adding menu

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and than set it as action bar in `onCreate`

```
....
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);    
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_helloworld_to_registration, menu);
    return true;
}
```